# Could not instantiate EventHubSourceProvider for Azure Databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

Using the steps documented in [structured streaming pyspark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#linking), I'm unable to create a dataframe in **pyspark** from the Azure Event Hub I have set up in order to read the stream data.

Error message is:
*java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider could not be instantiated*

I have installed the Maven libraries (com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.12 is unavailable) but none appear to work:
com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.15
com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.6

As well as `ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)` but the error message returned is:

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V*

The connection string is correct as it is also used in a console application that writes to the Azure Event Hub and that works.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please. Code in use is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Event Hub Namespace Name
NAMESPACE_NAME = "*myEventHub*"
KEY_NAME = "*MyPolicyName*"
KEY_VALUE = "*MySharedAccessKey*"

# The connection string to your Event Hubs Namespace
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={1};SharedAccessKey={2};EntityPath=ingestion".format(NAMESPACE_NAME, KEY_NAME, KEY_VALUE)

ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = connectionString

# For 2.3.15 version and above, the configuration dictionary requires that connection string be encrypted.
# ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I did the following:

1. Uninstall azure event hub library versions
2. Install com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.15 library version from Maven Central
3. Restart cluster
4. Validate by re-running code provided in the question

Comment: For me it works by just simply restarting the cluster, but I guess I'm lucky

Comment: I am also getting same error, I tried above solution, installed library com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.15 but no luck, is there any more suggestion ? Please help

Comment: I ended up using Scala instead of Python

Answer (score 6):

I received this same error when installing libraries with the version number com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.* on a Spark cluster running Spark 3.0 with Scala 2.12

For anyone else finding this via google - check if you have the correct Scala library version. In my case, my cluster is Spark v3 with Scala 2.12

Changing the "2.11" in the library version from the tutorial I was using to "2.12", so it matches my cluster runtime version, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to take this a step further. in the format method I had to add in this:

.format("org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider") directly.

Comment: Hi @Brad Hines, glad to see you got this to work for you. Can you let me know how you added .format("org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider") directly ?

Answer (score 0):

check the cluster scala version and the library version
Unisntall the older libraries and install :
com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.17
in the shared workspace(right click and install library) and also in the cluster